# Rename directory name using .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, dns

It's hard to explain, I would like to do something like below but I don't know how.

I currently own two different domain names and have one website.

Can I have two domains pointing to the same website but the URL only shows whatever domain is entered in the first place?

For example, when I type in 'domain123.com', it takes me to my website (IP address 111.222.333) with the URL shown as 'domain123.com'. Then when I type in 'domainABC.com', it also takes me to the same website (IP address 111.222.333), but the URL needs to show 'domainABC.com' instead of 'domain123.com'.

I guess I will need to redirect one of the two domains to the website, but how can I stop the URL changes the domain name?

I am not sure if I can just modify .htaccess to achieve above or if I also need to change the DNS, etc. to make this work.

Please help and many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your setup and your server permissions.

A nice way will be to change the docroot in the apache or nginx config.

If you don't have permissions to edit these configs, you can create a symbolic links so that the public folder of domain2 points to the public folder of domain1